# Microsoft Home Use Program - use more than one computer

Tags: microsoft-office, license

I purchased a copy of MS Office through [Microsoft Home Use Program (HUP)](http://www.msofficehup.com/en-IE/Default.aspx)
It basically allows you get a very cheap copy for home use if your employer owns the licence.

My question is:
Can I install it on more than one PC/laptop at home? I could not find anything in [FAQ](http://www.msofficehup.com/en-IE/Faq.aspx)

Thank you

**EDIT**

I was installing Office 2010
I found the following in the EULA:

> MICROSOFT SOFTWARE LICENSE TERMS
>
> ....
>
> 2 INSTALLATION AND USE RIGHTS. 
>   a. One Copy per Device. You may install one
>   copy of the software on one device.
>   That device is the “licensed device.”
>
> b. Licensed Device. You may only use
>   one copy of the software on the
>   licensed device at a time.
>
> c. Portable
>   Device. **You may install another copy
>   of the software on a portable device
>   for use by the single primary user of
>   the licensed device**.

[Here is the full copy of the licence](https://docs.google.com/Doc?docid=0AXGG1-_Iz-0aZDhzeG0ybl8xNDhjZzR0d3hobQ&hl=en_GB)

Comment: I wonder what they define as a portable device.  My desktop second desktop is portable if I unplug it from the wall and carry it around.

Comment: Yes, you are allowed to install on a main and secondary device.  Office 2007 also has a similar license.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is support in the HUP license (which is the same as a retail license for this discussion) for installing on two machines, a primary and a portable.  This is described in the EULA.

One site where you can see this explained is here:

http://news.office-watch.com/t/n.aspx?articleid=872&zoneid=9

The EULA for Office 2007 with the relevant portion highlighted is here:

http://news.office-watch.com/t/n.aspx?articleid=734&zoneid=13

The EULAs for all Microsoft products can be found here:

http://www.microsoft.com/About/Legal/EN/US/IntellectualProperty/UseTerms/Default.aspx

If you look at the 2010 agreement you can see the same "portable device" language.

Comment: thanks Mike, I actually started the installation and looked at the "microsoft software license terms"  and it indeed says under 2. INSTALLATION AND USE RIGHTS. c. Portable Device. You may install another copy of the software on a portable device for use by the single primary user of the licensed device.
It is Office 2010

Answer (score 0):

No, you are not allowed to install the software on more than one computer at a time.

But you can purchase more HUP licenses. In my home use program, I can buy more than one license, so I would expect that you can, too.

<sub>It may be technically possible to install the same licence twice using the same key.</sub>

Comment: thank torbengb, I looked at the licence closely after Mike's answer it it is allowed to install second copy of the software on portable device

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem to install MS Office (any version) on three computers, but only if the license states so up front. If so, then there is no problem.

It is known to be more difficult and time consuming to install MS Office 2010 (Professional Edition) from the Floppy Disk. Up to five hundred disks and up to three days to install on one computer, so to do this on three computers could take up to six days.

Comment: Floppy disks?? If you are installing from floppies, then you deserve such difficulties.

Comment: Indeed Floppies are more time consuming. It is best to go with a DVD but if one insists on Floppies, then that one must have a bit more time to do the installation. It is very frustrating to get to # 408 Disk and the 409th be missing. Therefore, if you are thinking of  installing from Floppies surfasb, you should do so only if you have several free days on your hands without having to take the garbage out.

Comment: @bung, just the overhead of cutting the file into so many pieces would take a monumental toll... Even forgetting about the overhead, its closer to 975 floppy disks for the file. you only get to use less floppies if they are of the high density variety.

Comment: This guy has to be a troll.  No way Office comes in floppies.

Comment: Soandos, I'm thinking of the 3 1/2" floppies. It would be a monumental toll and those that are up to it will save money but not the time. I would think, though not as long as installing Windows7 by Floppies, it would be a rather long time. It is immensely aggravating when you get near to the last one and that last disk has been sitting near to a horseshoe magnet. Surfasb, you need to look again if you think Windows 7 or MS Office does not come on Floppies.  Tut tut now!!!

Answer (score -1):

No.  You have a single license.  I believe depending on what package you have the TOS will be available with the software.

That is if you want a legal copy on all your computers.

Comment: thank Chris, I found a clause in the licence that allows use on 2nd portable device